# Online Finite Field Calculator

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, math-software, online-resources

I need to find an online Finite Field calculator with the following operations:
  Inverse
  SqrRoot
  Mult
  Div
I have found one a couple of days ago but lost the url, and cannot find it now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: thx but, I need something as the first one with SqrRoot and Inverses, online. Is for students, I cannot ask them to install anything

Comment: Maybe http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~algebra~calcff.en.html ? More customisable solution could be [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), and you may also use GAP there.

Comment: the first one does not work, and I do not know what u mean I could also use the GAP

Comment: SageMathCloud gives you access to a virtual machine on which you may install GAP. Of course, you can use Sage there as well, and then either use GAP via Sage (the version which is included in Sage), or maybe use finite fields arithmetic provided by Sage - can not advice on the latter and compare it with GAP, though. Perhaps both systems will match your needs.

Comment: Mhmmm, I see, but i need something handy for the students to use, and I'm sure there are online calculators for these operations

Comment: IMHO, might be helpful to post this question under tags `(math-software)` and `(symbolic-computation)`, maybe replacing `(finite-groups)` and `(galois-theory)` ...

Comment: I doubt there's such a thing online. There are several calculators for modulo a prime calculations, so they serve for the prime field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ , but for that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SageMathCloud (https://cloud.sagemath.com) can do *absolutely everything* you need online, for free.    Tell your students to:

1. Go to https://cloud.sagemath.com and create an account.
2. Click "New Project" under projects.
3. Open the project and click "+New" and click on "Sage Worksheet"
4. In the worksheet that comes up they can do pretty much anything related to finite field calculations.  Here is an image that shows how to do everything you requested in your question with a general finite field:

[image]

More comments:

```
k.<a> = GF(25)   # create the finite field of order 25 with generator a.  
                 # type a.minpoly() to find the poly that a satisfies

(3+a)*(5-2*a)    # do all standard arithmetic as usual
```

The implementation in Sage is extremely efficient for small-cardinality fields, and is built on top of [Givaro](http://ljk.imag.fr/CASYS/LOGICIELS/givaro/) and [Pari](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/).